# How to select only these ID which logged only one time during last 3 months based on Timestamp column?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have table in Oracle SQL like below:

```
ID   date
------------
11  | 2021-07-01 12:55:13.278
11  | 2021-06-01 12:55:13.278
22  | 2021-06-01 12:55:13.278
33  | 2021-05-01 12:55:13.278
```

And I need to select only these clients who logged only ONE time during last 3 months from current date (2021-09-28).

So as a result I need

```
ID   
----
11
```

Because only client with ID = 11 logged only ONE time (2021-07-01 12:55:13.278) during last 3 months.

I think that maybe sample of table is not large, but describions is clear. Be aware that format of column with data is probably timestamp with date and time and it needs special selection probably?

Comment: The key to the solution depends on the data type of the column you have labled as "date".  It _should_ be either DATE or TIMESTAMP.  If not - if it is varchar2 - then you have a fundamental design fail.  Also, "date" is a reserved word.  It can only be used as a column name if you enclose it in double quotes.  But you should never use double-quotes, as that creates case-sensitive names and makes life much more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd filter those who logged last three months and count them afterwards

```
select id
  from test_data
 where date_col > add_months(to_date('2021-09-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), -3)
 group by id
 having count(1) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID from tbl_name
WHERE 
DATE > add_months( sysdate, -3 )
group by ID having count(*) = 1
```

NOTE: reserved words like date souldnt be used as column name

Answer (score 0):

The DATA column looks like VARCHAR, just compare directly

```sql
select t1.id from tab1 t1 
 group by t1.id 
having count(case when t1.data > to_char(add_months(to_date('2021-09-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), -3), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                  then 1 else null end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
with x ( id , date_logon ) 
as 
(
select 11 , to_timestamp('2021-07-01 12:55:13.278','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from dual union all
select 11 , to_timestamp('2021-06-01 12:55:13.278','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from dual union all
select 22 , to_timestamp('2021-06-01 12:55:13.278','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from dual union all
select 33 , to_timestamp('2021-05-01 12:55:13.278','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from dual
), 
z as 
(
select id , min(date_logon) min_val, max(date_logon) max_val
from x group by id 
) 
select * from z where add_months(sysdate,-3) between min_val and max_val;

       ID MIN_VAL                                                                     MAX_VAL
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        11 01-JUN-21 12.55.13.278000000 PM                                             01-JUL-21 12.55.13.278000000 PM
```